# Typescript, how to handle href prop in component that can be Link or button?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a pagination component created using `styled-components`:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

const StyledPagination = styled(Link)<StyledProps>``
```

I use it in component:

```
const Pagination = ({
  number,
  href,
  disabled = false,
}: Props): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <StyledPagination
      $disabled={disabled}
      aria-label={disabled ? undefined : `Page ${number}`}
      aria-disabled={disabled}
      href={disabled ? undefined : href}
      as={disabled ? 'button' : undefined}
    >
      {number === DOTS ? <>&#8230;</> : number}
    </StyledPagination>
  );
};
```

When in component is passed prop `disabled`, I use prop `as` and change `Link` component to `button`. It works, but after introducing `strictNullChecks`, typescript is complaining about `href` prop:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Url'.
```

I now that I can write `new URL(href)`, but since `href` is optional prop, it will only complain about `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Url'.` If component is a `button`, it doesn't need `href` prop, so to get rid of it just use `href={undefined}`. I need a way to fix this error and allow `href` to be optional prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make the href prop explicitly optional in your StyledPagination component. Something like this,

```js
// ...before 
const StyledPagination = styled(Link)<StyledProps>``

// ...after
const StyledPagination = styled(Link)<StyledProps & { href?: string | Url }>``
```